# REACT: toggle class onClick, and call other function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react so please be patient - I'm sure this is a simple problem but I am having a lot of trouble figuring out a solution.

I have a set of buttons, when they are clicked I add an 'active' className to that button and remove it from any other buttons that might be active.

I also need to open a panel with content based on which button is clicked.

So far I have managed to toggle the className of the clicked button, but can't figure out how to only apply it to the button that is clicked (see code below)

```
<a onClick={this.buttonClick(1)} className={this.state.isButtonActive ? 'active' : null}>button text</a>
<a onClick={this.buttonClick(2)} className={this.state.isButtonActive ? 'active' : null}>button text</a>
```

and the function to toggle the active state and open appropriate panel based on the button clicked:

```
buttonClick(buttonNumber) {

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        isButtonActive: !prevState.isButtonActive
    }));

    openPanel(buttonNumber)
}
```

I have experimented with creating a child component for the button and toggling the className within the component, but then I can't trigger the openPanel() function as it is in the parent component.

I hope that makes sense - thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the problem is that you are sharing the same `state` for both buttons, so when you change it for one, it changes for the other. You should wrap your buttons in different components so that they have different state.

If you need a callback in the parent component to be called, pass it to the button components so that they can trigger that as well.

The button could look like this:

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = { isButtonActive: false }
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this)      
  }

  onClick () {
    this.setState({
      isButtonActive: !this.state.isButtonActive
    })

    this.props.openPanel(this.props.buttonNumber)
  }

  render () {

    return (
      <button onClick={this.onClick()} className={this.state.isButtonActive ? 'active' : null}>button text</a>
    )
  }
}
```

how the parent component could look like:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  onButtonClicked (number) {
    console.log(`Button ${number} was clicked`)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button buttonNumber={1} openPanel={this.onButtonClicked} />
        <Button buttonNumber={2} openPanel={this.onButtonClicked} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: thanks Mario. do you mean different componentes for each button (i have about 12 in total), or one component reused for each button? is there a different method for adding a click to a component, it's not working for me... eg. <Button onClick={this.onClick} /> doesn't trigger a click

Comment: you have one `Button` instance for each button. You need to pass the right props to it, I updated my example to reflect that.

Comment: thanks Mario F, makes sense. this works, however, how do I remove the `active` class from other buttons when a new button is clicked?

Comment: In that case I would keep the state as an array in the parent component, set the active state as true for the index of the button that was clicked, and false for the rest. Then I would pass the right active state to each button as a prop

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the common state for both the button.

Instead of storing a boolean value for active, you can store the numeral like

```
<a onClick={this.buttonClick(1)} className={this.state.isButtonActive === 1 ? 'active' : null}>button text</a>
<a onClick={this.buttonClick(2)} className={this.state.isButtonActive === 2 ? 'active' : null}>button text</a>
```

and Click action to

```
buttonClick(buttonNumber) {

    this.setState({
        isButtonActive: buttonNumber
    });

    openPanel(buttonNumber)
}
```